# Kobuki strange behaviour in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Indigo with Gazebo 5.1 in Ubuntu 14.04.2 64bits. I am executing the following commands:

```
roslaunch kobuki_gazebo kobuki_empty_world.launch 
roslaunch kobuki_keyop keyop.launch 
rosrun rviz rviz
```

And when teleoperating the robot moves properly in RViz but not in Gazebo: the rotating movements seem to be OK but going forward/backward is not working.

Also, at the beginning the robot simulation was shaky. I fixed that by removing the custom physics of the empty.world file in kobuki_gazebo package and this part is good now.

Any advice on how to debug the issue? Thank you!

Terminal output for  `roslaunch kobuki_gazebo kobuki_empty_world.launch` :

```
~/catkin_turtlebot$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch  ... logging to /home/jvgomez/.ros/log/39c6131c-f94b-11e4-95e6-7824afa13789/roslaunch-RR05-16926.log Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to interrupt Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://RR05:40114/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS  * /bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud_radius:
0.24  * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file: /opt/ros/indigo/s...  * /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id: /camera_depth_frame  * /depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min:
0.45  * /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height: 10  * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....  * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency:
30.0  * /rosdistro: indigo  * /rosversion: 1.11.10  * /use_sim_time: True

NODES   /
    bumper2pointcloud (nodelet/nodelet)
    cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
    depthimage_to_laserscan (nodelet/nodelet)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    laserscan_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    spawn_turtlebot_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master process[master]: started with pid [16941] ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
setting /run_id to 39c6131c-f94b-11e4-95e6-7824afa13789 
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [16954] started core service [/rosout] 
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [16978] 
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [16982]
process[spawn_turtlebot_model-4]: started with pid [16988] 
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5]: started with pid [16993] 
process[cmd_vel_mux-6]: started with pid [16997] 
process[bumper2pointcloud-7]: started with pid [17051] 
process[robot_state_publisher-8]: started with pid [17084] 
process[laserscan_nodelet_manager-9]: started with pid [17126] 
process[depthimage_to_laserscan-10]: started with pid [17146] 
[ INFO] [1431506222.525472510]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin. 
[ INFO] [1431506222.526713615]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting... 
[ INFO] [1431506223.160382075,
0.030000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1431506223.195195975, 0.060000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready. 
[ INFO] [1431506224.215947081,
0.740000000]: Camera Plugin (robotNamespace = /), Info: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/' 
[ INFO] [1431506224.249416155, 0.740000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to "" 
[spawn_turtlebot_model-4] process has finished cleanly log file: /home/jvgomez/.ros/log/39c6131c-f94b-11e4-95e6-7824afa13789/spawn_turtlebot_model-4*.log
```

**UPDATE** I have also tested the playground demo (http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki_gazebo?distro=indigo), everything loads OK and visualization is also OK, but the robot does not move at all.

**UPDATE 2** I have tried TurtleBot tutorials, but with turtlebot_gazebo from source and, as before, everything is visualized, I can even see the pointclouds on RViz, but teleoperation still does not work and a couple of errors appear in RViz: Grid>Transform>For frame [odom]: frame [odom] does not exist and RobotModel>Transform>No transform from [wheel_left_link] to [base_footprint] and the same for right wheel. Obviously I am missing to launch something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209126/kobuki-strange-behaviour-in-gazebo/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-05-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2015-05-13**:
I'm facing similar problems both moving the TB2 and [the arm](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8047/grasping-solving-problems-introduced-when/). I guess that all these problems comes from gazebo5 not understanding current (indigo) URDF  and  tags, but we need a guru's insight

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-05-13**:
I have tested the same code in Gazebo4.1.3 and it works like a charm, so it is a Gazebo5 problem.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-26**:
@jorge: is there an issue at Gazebo's issue tracker(s) for this? Or is "gazebo5 not understanding current (indigo) URDF  and  tags" a feature, not a bug?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2015-05-28**:
not sure, but I bet for option 2. So no issue.... just wait for updated tutorials on using ROS-Gazebo5, that should come with Jade (as Jade uses gazebo 5 by default)

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-14**:
@jorge Where can I see anything related to the URDF  and  tags in Gazebo 5? Any changelog or something. I cannot find anything. Thanks!

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2015-07-15**:
I also failed to find any information about integrating ROS robots with Gazebo 5. However, as JAde uses Gazebo 5, I expect that new tutorials will come soon.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-15**:
Taking a look at the [change log](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/Changelog.md), I saw the following line: `Change behavior of Joint::SetVelocity, add Joint::SetVelocityLimit(unsigned int, double) * Pull request #1218 * Issue #964` for Gazebo 5.0.0. I will go deeper into this

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-15**:
@jorge I found the reason :) Check my edited answer. It could be helpful for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is a Gazebo 5 problem as pointed out in the comments of the original post. I solved it installing the latest Gazebo4 version.

**EDIT**: And I finally found the reason!! https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/1218/change-behavior-of-odejoint-setvelocity/diff

Point 14 in Gazebo 5.0.0: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/Changelog.md

The behaviour of the SetMaxForce functions changed, therefore Kobuki plugin is deprecated. The solution (but I am not sure if this is a workaround or proper solution) is something like: https://github.com/mayfieldrobotics/kobuki_desktop/commit/4246c6e4330f39725df3eb39a0b77a7fcc6185b1

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [m4k](https://answers.ros.org/users/26854/m4k/) on 2016-06-22**:
was this fixing the wobble / shake of the kobuki base? My kobuki is wobbling in indigo/gazebo5 (with changes and compiled from source)

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-06-22**:
@m4k Yes that solved it for me.